# Probability distribution of $P(|R(f)|=k)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

Let $f$ be a uniformly selected random function that maps the set $[n] = \{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself, so $f(1),...,f(n)$ are i.i.d. and uniformly distributed over $[n]$. If $R(f)$ denotes the range of the function $f(·)$. In other words, $R(f) = \{y ∈ [n] : (∃x ∈ [n] : f(x) = y)\}$. Try to compute the probability of $|R(f)|=k$, for  $\forall k\leq n$.

For example, for $n=6$, for instance, $f[1,2,3,4,5,6]=[2,2,3,3,3,5]$, then $|R(f)|=3$, since there are three numbers $(2,3,5)$ appears in the range. What is $P(|R(f)|=3)$?

The expectation is given:
$E(|R(f)|)=n(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n)$. I have tried several expressions of possible probability distributions but nothing is accord with this expectation after check.

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: `\{1,2,3\}` shows $\{1,2,3\}$. More formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $$1~1|1|1~1~1 \implies P(|R(f)|=3) = \frac{\binom{5}{2}}{2^5}$$
$$P(|R(f)|=k) = \frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{2^{k-1}}$$

Comment: @Galaxy The denominator should be 2^(n-1) right? I think it's incorrect, check when k=1, the result is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is
\begin{equation}
      P(|R(f)|=k)=\frac{\binom{n}{k} k!F (n,k)}{n^n},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
      F (n,k)=F(n-1,k-1)+kF(n-1,k),\quad F(n,1)=F(n,n)=1.
\end{equation}

Since $f$ is uniformly selected, there are $n^n$ kinds of equiprobable mappings, yields the denominator.

Suppose $|R(f)|=k$. Firstly choosing $k$ images, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ probabilities. Secondly, mapping $n$ different pre-images into these $k$ different images. For the case $n=6, k=3$, see the figure below.

This process is like putting n different balls into k different boxes.

The formula of putting n different balls into k same boxes is $F(n,k)$, thinking it as a recursive process yields $F(n,k)=F(n-1,k-1)+kF(n-1,k),\quad F(n,1)=F(n,n)=1.$Since these boxes are different, we need to time $F(n,k)$ with $k!$.

I have checked for case $n=4$:

$P(|R(f)=1|)=\frac{4}{256}$

$P(|R(f)=2|)=\frac{6*2*7}{256}$

$P(|R(f)=3|)=\frac{4*6*6}{256}$

$P(|R(f)=4|)=\frac{1*24*1}{256}$

Their sum is 1. Besides, the expectation is 2.734375, which is accord to the result given by the expression of expectation.

[image]

Comment: How did you derive it?

Comment: @ClementC. Details added